# I cant seem to execute Javascript code on a Chrome Extension I made

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest

Lately I have been coding a Chrome Extension that would refresh the page whenever certain component was present on the webpage, the code works perfectly, the problem comes when uploading the Extension

It seems to do nothing, not even the Console log

This is what the html looks like:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="ad.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This would be the Javascript:

```
console.log("No hay anuncio");

/*const ad = document.getElementById("simple-ad-badge:d")
if(ad != null) {
    location.replace(location.href);
}else{
    console.log("No hay anuncio");
}*/
```

And this would be the manifest file:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Ad",
  "description": "Ad",
  "version": "1.0",
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "ad.html",
    "default_icon": "hello.png"
  }
}
```

I have tried looking up what to add to make it work because I know there are parts missing that would allow the Extension to work, but I haven't been able to find anything recent, everything is either for Manifest 2 or with outdated stuff

Nothing really ended up happening as I wasn't able to find an answer